# Browser developer tools: what is the Position of the HTML element?

Tags: css, layout, position, browser, web-developer-toolbar

Modern Web Developer tools (in Chrome / FF / IE, eg.) provide a way to see the "Box Model" and "Computed CSS Properties" of a particular element. However;

*Is there a way to monitor the **final** computed/layout position easily with such tools?*

---

Preferably absolute, but within the parent container is also suitable. I am amendable to using any of the previously mentioned [Windows] browsers, but prefer to use Chrome.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

In Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE11+, when an element is selected, you can access this element in the console window by typing:

`$0`

You can then query and manipulate using the [Javascript DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), which has a very useful method called [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

So all you have to do is type the following into the console window when an element is selected:

`$0.getBoundingClientRect()`

and the browser will return an object such as:

`{ x: 1081, y: 72, width: 49, height: 28, top: 72, right: 1130, bottom: 99, left: 1081 }`

I find it very useful to have the following live expression in Chrome Dev Tools:

`!!$0 && JSON.stringify($0.getBoundingClientRect())`

Comment: Are those values correct? How can an element have an height of `28` when it starts at `72` and ends at `99` (`99 - 72 = 27`? Same for the width...)

Comment: in Chrome Dev Tools, you can also add a "live expression" with `$0` to get updated values

Answer (score 21):

Chrome dev tools -> Settings -> General -> Elements -> Show Rulers.

You can also install Chrome plugins that will give you a little more functionality.

Comment: The rulers are fairly neat, but not precise or dynamic enough. I'd like to be able to keep my eye on a dynamically changing value during page reflows, much like the current "Box Model" display. For the plugin, do you have a recommendation? The few I looked up seemed more oriented to general site development and issue identification.

Comment: I haven't really needed anything in addition to the basic rulers, so I don't really have an educated recommendation on the plugin.  There seem to be quite a few of them out there and the functionality looks like it may be close to what you need.